# Uncaught SyntaxtError: Unexpected identifier when trying to import React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, ecmascript-6

I have a simple React component that I am trying to incorporate into a web page. The component looks as follows (in file `like_button.js`). This JSX I am compiling using babel v6.4.1.

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';

const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { liked: false };
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.liked) {
            return 'You liked this.';
        }

        return (
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ liked: true })}>
                Like
            </button>
        );
    }
}

const frmReg = document.querySelector('#frmReg');
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), frmReg)
```

The HTML page (index.php) that I am trying to consume this, looks as follows.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <!-- Load our React component. -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="frmReg"></div>
</body>
<!-- <script src="assets/js/like_button.js"></script> -->
<script src="assets/js/admincomponent.js"></script>
</html>
```

My `package.json` file looks as follows.

```
{
  "name": "react_dt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

Also have included `.babelrc` included in the project root, which appears as follows.

```
{
    presets: ["es2015", "react"],
    plugins: ["transform-es2015-modules-amd"]
}
```

However, when I try to run this in the browser, I don't see a thing in the page. Further, in the dev tools console, I am having the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`, with the `import React, { Component } from 'react';` statement highlighted.

I tried the same **without** the import statement and **got it to work flawlessly**. So basically it boils down to a problem with the `import`. Upon research, I have read that this is a problem from **ES5** to **ES6(ES2015)**. Further, I have found about 5 odd questions on the same issue, that which none of their solutions helped me to find the solution.

What is wrong? Why won't it let me do the import?

Comment: How come your package.json does not contain a dependency of react itself.

Comment: @curlyBraces Umm... uhh.. I don't know.. :D Should that be there?

Comment: @RomeoSierra yes, if you want people (including yourself in the future) to be able able to get everything needed by executing `npm install`. You probably have React installed globally, so it's on your machine but not expressed as a dependency of your project. Doing `npm install` on a clean machine right now means you'll have a non-working solution.

Comment: @vlaz Thank you for summing that up..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install the `react` and `react-dom` package. When you are importing the the package that means package is installed in `node_modules`. It will search the package in `node_modules` folder and then show error if not found.

Are you compiling your javascript file using babel? Please use babel compiled javascript in the project. You can use [babel-node](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-node.html) for compiling your javascript to es5